# C programming invoking "at command" in Linux

Tags: c, linux

how could i delay or invoke echo command using at job? I want to print something at a specified time...thank you!

like echo "hello world" | at 12:00 and pass this command to system(). I already tried to update DB using "at job" and it is doing great but i want also to print something after i update it...thanks in advance! =)

Comment: Where do you expect `at` to print it to?

Comment: Does it need to be at a particular time, or is just important that it happens once a day?

Answer (score 2):

Just running `echo` doesn't quite make sense, since there is nowhere for the output to go (unless you redirect to a file).  This example will send a broadcast message to all terminals at 12:34

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f = popen("at 1234", "w");
    fprintf(f, "echo 'Hello World' | wall");
    fclose(f);
    printf("Job scheduled\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe that `at` and `cron` jobs usually send their output by email.

Comment: @Greg - thanks for your idea. maybe somehow this answers my question but i need the time to be variable also...let's say i can set the time at any period of the day.